# Need help to solve and find the weekly pay accordingly

Tags: c++

The problem is in the screenshot.
[image]

And this is my code and my approach. But the results are off, I think the hour values and the rate value is the pay_rate function is not updated accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
float pay_rate(float, float*);
float total_pay(float, float, float*);
int main() {
  float h, rate, total_salary = 0;
  printf("Input worked hours: ");
  scanf("%f", &h);
  pay_rate(h, &rate);
  // printf("%f", rate);
  total_pay(h ,rate,&total_salary);
  printf("\n%f", total_salary);
  
}

float pay_rate(float hour, float* rate) {
  float temp = 0;
  if (0 < hour && hour <= 40)
  {
    *rate = 12.5;
    hour = (hour)-40;
    // printf("\n%f", hour)/;
  } else if (0 < hour && hour <= 4) {
    *rate = 15;
    hour = hour-4;
    // printf("\n%f", *hour);
  } else if (hour > 0) {
    *rate = 20;
    // printf("\n%f",*hour);
  }
  return *rate;
}

float total_pay(float hours, float rate, float* salary){
  *salary = rate * hours;
  return *salary;
  
}
```

When I input 41 hours, the result is 820. But the result has to be `40*12.5` then `+1*15` which equals `515`.

Comment: The literal reason *debuggers* were invented. The rate is *progressive*. The first 40 hours should net you 12.5 per, the added hour should net you an additional 15. You're code, on the other hand, calculates a *single* rate based on the total hours, then multiplies the entire hours-worked against it. `pay_rate` is useless, afaict.

Comment: A few hints: remove the "else if" and just use three if statements; instead of returning rate in pay_rate, add up the total_pay/salary in each if clause and return the salary; you don't need to pass rate and salary as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the question. And therefore even your manually expected output is wrong.

First you need to calulate a base salary rate, which is only dependent on the category A or B or C or D.

The category is an input parameter. It must be read by read from the user (A or B or C or D) and then the base salry rate is fixed.

---

Then, depending on the worked hours, part (and only part) of the hours over a given threshold, will be multiplied with a factor.

So, if it is over 44, then only the hours over 44 will be multiplied with 2. The numbers above 40 and less/equal than 44 will be multiplied by 1.5. And the hours bgetween 0 and 40 will be paid with the base salary rate.

In simple C++ you could write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// Get the pay rate based in the pay category
double pay_rate(const char payCategory) {
    double result = 0;
    if (payCategory == 'A') 
        result = 12.5;
    else if (payCategory == 'B') 
        result = 15;
    else if (payCategory == 'C') 
        result = 20;
    else if (payCategory == 'D') 
        result = 25;
    else
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid Pay Category\n\n";
    return result;
}

// Calculate the toal weekly pay based on pay category and hours worked
double total_pay(const char payCategory, const unsigned int hours) {
    
    // The result
    double pay = 0;
    
    // Get base hourly rate
    double hourlyRate = pay_rate(payCategory);
    
    // Was the working time more than 44 hours?
    if (hours > 44)
        pay = (hours-44) * hourlyRate * 2 + 4 * hourlyRate * 1.5 + 40 * hourlyRate;
    // NOt more than 44. Maybe more than 40?
    else if (hours > 40)
        pay = (hours-40) * hourlyRate * 1.5 + 40 * hourlyRate;
    else
        // Just in the range of 0-4ß
        pay = hours * hourlyRate;
    return pay;
}

int main() {
    // Give user instruction. Enter Pay Category and number of hours worked
    std::cout << "Enter payment category (one of A,B,C,D) and number of hours worked:\n";
    
    // Get input from user and validate it
    char payCategory = '\0';
    unsigned int hours = 0;
    
    if ((std::cin >> payCategory >> hours) and (payCategory=='A' or payCategory=='B' or payCategory=='C' or payCategory=='D'))
    
        // Input was valid. SHow result
        std::cout << "\n\n\nTotal salary:  " << total_pay(payCategory, hours);
        
    else
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Invalid Input\n\n";
}
```

.

---

.

With a littel bit more advanced approch we would made the code data driven. Meaning, you just give the data, so the category data and the range data.

With that, you can simply modify values and the logic and code will be the same.

See for example this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<char, double> salaryByCategory {{'A', 12.5}, {'B', 15}, {'C', 20}, {'D', 25}};
std::map<unsigned int, double> overtimeFactor{{0,1},{40,1.5},{44,2}};

int main() {
    // Give user instruction. Enter Pay Category and number of hours worked
    std::cout << "Enter payment category (one of A,B,C,D) and number of hours worked:\n";
    
    // Get input from user and validate it
    char payCategory = '\0';
    unsigned int hours = 0;
    
    if ((std::cin >> payCategory >> hours) and salaryByCategory.count(payCategory) == 1) {
        
        // Get base salary based on category
        double baseSalary{salaryByCategory[payCategory]};
        
        // This is the resulting payment that we will output at the end
        double payment{};
        
        // Calculate total payment
        for (auto riter = overtimeFactor.rbegin(); riter != overtimeFactor.rend(); ++riter) {
            
            // If we are above an upper border
            if (hours > riter->first) {
                
                // Calculate hours that are above the max threshold
                const unsigned int hoursAbove = hours - riter->first;
                
                // Payment for this range
                payment += (hoursAbove * riter->second * baseSalary);
                
                // New hours (without the already calculated one)
                hours -= hoursAbove;
            }
        }
        // Show result
        std::cout << "\n\nResult: " << payment << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Invalid Input\n\n";
}
```

Comment: big thanks to you, i really misunderstood the problem.